# Evaluate the limit(0/0) case

Tags: calculus

evaluate the limit using L'hop
$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1}{2t}\int_{x-t}^{x+t}vf'(v)dv $$

how to apply fundamental theorm in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Let 
$$F(t)=\int_{x-t}^{x+t}vf'(v)dv$$
so

$$F'(t)=(x+t)f'(x+t)+(x-t)f'(x-t)$$
hence by l'Hospital's rule we have
$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1}{2t}\int_{x-t}^{x+t}vf'(v)dv=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{F'(t)}{2}=xf'(x) $$
assuming that $f'$ is continuous at $x$.